# JavaScript windows.onscroll event

Tags: javascript

why doesn't this piece of code work

```
window.onscroll = scroll;
function scroll() {
    if (window.pageYOffset == 400)
        alert('alert message');
}
```

while this works?

```
window.onscroll = scroll;
    function scroll() {
        if (window.pageYOffset > 400)
            alert('alert message');
    }
```

Comment: Obviously because `pageYOffset` is larger than 400?

Comment: Why wouldn't `>=` work for you? Why do you need strict equality?

Comment: no, i started scolling from pageYOffset == 0. with the first code, at the point of reaching 400, i din't get the alert.

Comment: @RaulRene i was curious why == didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because the `onscroll` event does not trigger at every pixel scrolled.

**[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kye2F/)** for example, which does a `console.log(window.pageYOffset)` when `onscroll` is fired and check the output. It's high chance you won't get `400` there.

Comment: does this difference between values varies with browser, Raul Rene?

Comment: It depends how the user scrolls: If he's using the mouse wheel then scroll moves by predefined steps (usually a number of text lines, it depends on the OS), if you drag the scroll bar then it will depend how fast you move it and how long the page is.

Comment: @user3559645 I wanted to say that it does not depend on the browser, but apparently Pablo says that it depends on the OS. This is something I particularly was not aware of.
Try the fiddle out, try scrolling slower/faster or switching between mouse/touchpad to see the differences

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle and you will see, that scrolling doesn't report every pixel - or to be exactly, most browsers don't scoll smoothly, but in certain steps:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/83nUe/